# Missing Quick Settings Panel in Ultra Power Saving after upgrade to android 6.0.1 (Samsung S5)

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, settings, quick-settings

I have recently upgraded to Android 6.0.1 in Samsung Galaxy S5. After the upgrade the Quick Settings Panel in Ultra Power Saving Mode has disappeared. The panel was available before by swiping the top of the screen, just like in the normal Non-Power Saving Mode. Currently there is only

- time and date,
- a gear icon for accessing settings,
- a button to turn off the Ultra Power Saving Mode.

How can I bring back the "Quick Settings with a swipe" feature in Ultra Power Saving mode?